# Http call being made twice with parameters reset

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm making a GET request to retrieve posts, but when I load the page, it makes the first request with the correct `page` query in the request URL but then immediately makes another request with `page` set to 1. Here's the console output when I make a request for `page=3`:

```
"page: 3"
bolt.js:54 Object {method: "GET", url: "http://localhost/api/v1/content/news?order=datepublish%20DESC&limit=10&page=3", headers: Object}
bolt.js:54 Object {method: "GET", url: "http://localhost/api/v1/content/news?order=datepublish%20DESC&limit=10&page=1", headers: Object}
bolt.js:58 "success function called."
posts.controller.js:35 Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
bolt.js:58 "success function called."
```

So you can see it's clearly making two GET requests, but only returning one set of data (the latter, with `page=1`.

In my `posts.controller.js`, I have:

```
activate();

function activate() {

    $scope.isLoading = 1;
    $scope.previousLink = 0;

    return getPosts($stateParams.page).then(function(data) {
        $scope.isLoading = 0;
        $rootScope.pageLoading = 0;
    });
}

function getPosts(page) {

    console.log("page: " + page);

    var contenttype = 'news';
    var order = 'datepublish%20DESC';
    var limit = 10;

    return Bolt.getRecords(contenttype, order, limit, page)
        .then(function(data){

            // Below is line 35
            console.log(data);
            $scope.posts = data.data.data;

        });
}
```

And the `Bolt` service (bolt.js):

```
function getRecords(contenttype, order, limit, page) {

    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url:    API_BASE_URL + 'content/' + contenttype +
                    '?order=' + order +
                    '&limit=' + limit +
                    '&page=' + page,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':     'application/json',
            'Accept':           'application/json'
        }
    };

    // Below is line 54
    console.log(request);

    return $http(request)
        .success(function(data){

            // Below is line 58
            console.log("success function called.");                        
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(error){
            return error;
        });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like something else is calling your `getRecords` function. Perhaps some debugging code somewhere? Have you tried putting a debugger breakpoint in `getRecords` so you can see what the stack trace is each time it's called?

Comment: Are you sure the first request is not a preflight of a cross-domain AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are asynchronous function calls made within a watch that are executed via the digest cycle.

Check if you have used your `getRecords`  or `getPosts` function anywhere else in your code. Perhaps is related to watching some variable related to your `pages` parameter.

Good luck.